# Write a method GetAverage() to read 3 numbers from keyboard and return their average

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have tried to write the code, for this task, but I am getting an error with my 'ReadLine'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double average = GetAverage();
        Console.WriteLine("The average of the numbers is: " + average);
    }
    public static double GetAverage()
    {
        double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter the first number: "));
        double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter the second number: "));
        double num3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine("Enter the third number: "));
        return (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell us what the error is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `Console.ReadLine()` does not accept any argument. It read data from the console and return an string.

You should use `Console.WriteLine` for printing data on console screen and use `Console.ReadLine` to getting data from console :

```
public static double GetAverage()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number: ");
    double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number: ");
    double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the third number: ");
    double num3 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    return (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3;
}
```

Comment: Maybe change `double.Parse()` in `double.TryParse()` to handle input mishaps